# how to use simultaneously one modifier to 2 objects

Tags: modifiers

I want to smooth 2 different objects which are made from one bigger therefore they have some touching points. When I use the modifier one by one, they both change shapes that are not touching themselves. So my idea is how can I use the modifier simultaneously on 2 objects that modifier will treat them as one?

Comment: maybe show a screenshot because to make it easier to understand

Comment: Ctrl+J to join them. I can't think of any other way to have two objects and treat them as one.

Comment: Even as one object, smoothing will pull apart disconnected meshes. You could either move them closer so they touch after smoothing, or as one object merge some vertices so they are always connected. Would need more info on your scene to know which would work better.